# Compiling phantom.js to LLVM IR

Tags: c++, qt, clang, phantomjs

I downloaded the phantomjs source off of [their github](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs). I am trying to compile phantomjs into LLVM bytecode. However, when I run

```
> clang -S -emit-llvm main.cpp
```

It keeps saying:

```
In file included from main.cpp:31:
./utils.h:34:10: fatal error: 'QtGlobal' file not found
#include <QtGlobal>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Do I need to install Qt or something?

*BTW, I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the best place to ask this, but I couldn't think of any other SE site that would be better.*

Comment: [They show](http://phantomjs.org/build.html) how to build phantomjs and [they say](https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=1087) clang is not supported.

Comment: @DrewDormann so that means that they haven't switched to Qt5?